# Understanding of host route table

Tags: networking, tcp, routes, mask, subnet

I have the host computer with Ethernet adapter configured by this way: IP address 192.170.100.10, subnet mask 255.255.255.0. There is also hardware device which works like IP server, configured as: 192.170.100.20, 255.255.255.0. When I connect this device to the host Ethernet adapter, the following information is added to `route print` command output (Windows):

```
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
    192.170.100.0    255.255.255.0   192.170.100.10  192.170.100.10       20
   192.170.100.10  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       20
  192.170.100.255  255.255.255.255   192.170.100.10  192.170.100.10       20
```

I need some explanation of this output: how these entries are added, how they are used to route network packets 192.170.100.* to this adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
192.170.100.0    255.255.255.0   192.170.100.10  192.170.100.10       20
```

Means that anything on the 192.170.100.0 network will use 192.170.100.10 as it's gateway

```
192.170.100.10  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       20
```

Means that anything looking for 192.170.100.10 will actually get sent to the loopback (local) address.

```
192.170.100.255  255.255.255.255   192.170.100.10  192.170.100.10       20
```

Is the broadcast address for the 192.170.100.0 network.

Answer (score 2):

Line 1: Send everything that goes to 192.170.100.* out via your network card at 192.170.100.10, if no rule exists, that is more special

Line 2: Send packets to yourself NOT via cour network card, but via Loopback

Line 3: Send broadcasts via your network card.

As there is no rule for anything other than 192.170.100.* you will not be able to reach other nets